# Extracting data to a variable from a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a database query where I want to get the id number of the folder into the `@eFolderID` variable

```
DECLARE @eFolderId varchar(30)
SET @eFolderId = NULL
  
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM ProcessSupportMap
SET @eFolderId = EFOLDERID 
WHERE  Number = 'B0261109'
```

I want:

```
SET @eFolderId = EFOLDERID WHERE Number = 'B0261109'
```

I don't know where to put it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [SELECT @local_variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement to set a local variable to the value of an expression:

```
DECLARE @eFolderId varchar(30)
 
SELECT TOP 1  @eFolderId = EFOLDERID
FROM ProcessSupportMap
WHERE Number = 'B0261109'
```

Additional notes:

- As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), *if the SELECT statement returns more than one value, the variable is assigned the last value that is returned* and *if the SELECT statement returns no rows, the variable retains its present value. If expression is a scalar subquery that returns no value, the variable is set to NULL*
- You may also consider using [SET @local_variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the value returned by the subquery to the variable:

```
SET @eFolderId = (
  SELECT TOP 1 EFOLDERID 
  FROM ProcessSupportMap 
  WHERE Number = 'B0261109'
)
```